# What file types does MarkLogic support?

Tags: search-engine, bigdata, marklogic

I'm a student and I want to find a search engine for big data. I found MarkLogic Server but I don't know what file types it supports. Does it support doc, docx, pdf, xml, ppt, pptx, etc.? What other types are supported?

Answer (score 3):

At low level, MarkLogic supports storage of xml, plain text, and binary. XML is fully searchable, including range indexes for faceted search. Text is only full-text searchable. Binary is not searchable as is, but there are facilities to extract meta information, and text out of many binary formats. You can find more details about the latter in the online documentation:

http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/search-dev/binary-document-metadata#chapter

There is a sample application that shows this functionality:

http://developer.marklogic.com/code/document-discovery

HTH!

Comment: Thank you for your help, so that's how it is, it's support so many type